# onServiceConnected not getting called , getting a null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-service

I had developed a bound service as a separate project & I am trying to access the service from a client but I somehow I am getting

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-08 12:00:40.898  3206  3206 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-08 12:00:40.898  3206  3206 E AndroidRuntime:    at    com.test.binder.BinderServiceActivity.onClick(BinderServiceActivity.java:61)
08-08 12:00:40.898  3206  3206 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3526)
08-08 12:00:40.898  3206  3206 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14139)
08-08 12:00:40.898  3206  3206 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-08 12:00:40.898  3206  3206 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-08 12:00:40.898  3206  3206 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

08-08 12:00:40.898  3206  3206 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4725)
   08-08 12:00:40.898  3206  3206 E AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

I am suspecting that onServiceConnected is not getting called.Can someone help me resolving this.

Thanks in Advance,

Please find the client code below :

```
public class BinderServiceActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private static final String TAG = "LogActivity";
ILogService logService;
LogConnection conn;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

// Request bind to the service
conn = new LogConnection(); // 
Intent intent = new Intent("com.test.binder.ILogService"); // 
intent.putExtra("version", "1.0"); // 
bindService(intent, conn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE); // 

// Attach listener to button
((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(this);
}

class LogConnection implements ServiceConnection { // 

public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) { // 
  logService = ILogService.Stub.asInterface(service); // 
  Log.i(TAG, "connected");
}

public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) { // 
  logService = null;
  Log.i(TAG, "disconnected");
}

}

public void onClick(View button) {
try {

  logService.log_d("LogClient", "Hello from onClick()"); // 
  Message msg = new Message(Parcel.obtain()); // 
  msg.setTag("LogClient");
  msg.setText("Hello from inClick() version 1.1");
  logService.log(msg); // 
} catch (RemoteException e) { // 
  Log.e(TAG, "onClick failed", e);
}

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
Log.d(TAG, "onDestroyed");

unbindService(conn); // 

logService = null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have not posted complete source including Service it would be difficult to snatch your problem. You can download the [`Demo Source`](https://github.com/lalit3686/ServiceLifeCycle) for each type of Service Binding with example and get a quick idea. The demo contains Binding of Service using three types

> 1.)  Binding using IBinder
>
> 2.)  Binding using Messenger
>
> 3.)  Binding using AIDL

Comment: I am getting null pointer exception at  logService.log_d("LogClient", "Hello from onClick()"); because logService is null.